# Running couchbase on AWS under auto scaling

Tags: couchbase

I want to run couchbase on AWS EC2. Since my traffic is cyclic in nature, can I run Couchbase under auto-scaling. Since there are a lot of steps required to add/remove a node, I was wondering if this is the right approach. Has anybody tried it ?

Comment: I think just avoiding auto scaling with Couchbase would be ideal, provision for what you need at the top end of your cycle and let it run, app servers can go up and down but I think constantly rebalancing your cluster is asking for problems.

Comment: Even I think the same. Just wanted to know if I am the only one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been done before. Here is a high level list of the things you'd have to do:

1. Define which Couchbase metrics you need to use to base your scaling considerations on
2. Create a script to get those metrics from Couchbase and put them into Cloudwatch using Couchbase Rest API or CLI.
3. Create an AMI with Couchbase installed and OS configured.
4. Script the addition of one or more new nodes (using Couchbase Rest API or CLI), plus a rebalance, as a response to Auto-scaling
5. Script the removal and rebalance of nodes (using Couchbase Rest API or CLI), as a response to contraction in auto-scaling.

With you reliying on rebalances here, you will have to watch how long your rebalances take and perhaps tune your cluster (e.g. move more vBuckets at once and other settings) and usage of Couchbase for faster rebalances (e.g. if you have large views, they can have an effect on rebalances). Normally rebalances are meant to be a background process and take as long as they take, but that may not be appropriate in this particular use. Only you can answer that.

Comment: I have almost scripted this the way you have mentioned. I was concerned about the rebalance as it is resource consuming and puts significant load on other nodes. So I believe its not an anti pattern as auto scaling a data store is not a standard practice. I will try this on my cluster anyways.

Comment: If rebalance is that draining, then you have your cluster sized incorrectly, problem with your schema or some other problem most likely. Sizing a cluster is about day to day operations, but also maintenance (e.g. rebalances).

When you say "significant load" what do you mean exactly? which resources? CPU? Memory? Disk? Network? Does it effect front end operations of the cluster and if so how? Disk write queue, lower ops per second? etc etc etc. I need more information is all.